# Installing Django-Fabric-AWS with pip, invalid syntax?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In process of deploying Django on EC2, I'm following a step in [this](https://ashokfernandez.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/deploying-a-django-app-to-amazon-aws-with-nginx-gunicorn-git/) guide that requires me to install [Fabric](https://github.com/ashokfernandez/Django-Fabric-AWS).

In the terminal of Pycharm, I first confirm pip is working by running `pip` and in the project directory. It is, so then I type in the command that I've been instructed, `pip install -r fabfile/requirements.txt` which produces the following:

```
Collecting Fabric==1.4.3 (from -r fabfile/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached Fabric-1.4.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-icytzvd1\Fabric\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        from fabric.version import get_version
      File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-icytzvd1\Fabric\fabric\version.py", line 104
        print get_version('all')
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
←[31mCommand "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-icytzvd1\Fabric←[0m
```

My untrained eyes do not see a syntax error that I can recognize. I looked in `C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\1` with hidden files shown, and there is no `pip-build-icytzvd1` folder.

I'm completely inexperienced with AWS. If a solution to this problem is worth finding, where could I find the solution? If it isn't worth finding a solution to this, is there an up-to-date guide to manually deploy Django on EC2 using Nginx, Gunicorn, PostreSQL, and Amazon AMI?

edit:

```
Collecting Fabric
  Downloading Fabric-1.10.2.tar.gz (212kB)
Collecting paramiko>=1.10 (from Fabric)
  Downloading paramiko-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (169kB)
Collecting pycrypto!=2.4,>=2.1 (from paramiko>=1.10->Fabric)
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446kB)
Collecting ecdsa>=0.11 (from paramiko>=1.10->Fabric)
  Downloading ecdsa-0.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86kB)
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, ecdsa, paramiko, Fabric
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    Complete output from command D:\env\Django\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\pycrypto\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nggph54n-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\env\Django\include\site\python3.5\pycrypto:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    warning: PCTBuildPy: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: did my solution work?

Comment: Unfortunately `pip install Fabric` didn't work, I tried it again just now and posted the error in the OP. I gave up and did everything manually, but if it can work I'd still like to use fabric.

Comment: This is an error in installing pycrypto a dependency of fabric. ANd it seems that you are on windows. Installing libraries on windows is often a pain. a search for pycrypto on windows or the exact error might reveal something.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric 1.4.3 that old. Really old the current version is [1.10.2](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/releases). The reason that you can't find that temporary folder is because it's created by pip when you try to install fabric and cleared out afterwards. You can however see the current [version.py](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/version.py) or if you check out the project you will be able to see it for the version you are trying to install. The current version code looks a bit different from what you posted:

```
print(get_version('all'))
```

However I can't figure out why the following should produce an error either.

```
print get_version('all')
```

Why don't you just install the latest version of Frabric by using this requirements file: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/dev-requirements.txt ? chances are you probably have the requirements installed already. In that case just do

```
pip install Fabric
```

Comment: I see that topic is from 2015, but for the offsprings I want to mention that python3 requires print to be used with overhangs.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue.  e5c5 is correct.  It is a pycrypto installation issue.  Try installing pycrypto as a standalone pip installation.  It will probably throw an error message and ask you to install Visual Studio c++.

`warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools`